# Android - Can you optimize your views so that they don't go through performTraversals on making some view GONE?

Tags: android, view

For example, when you make some View to GONE, Android goes through all of your views, trying to determine if it should resize/move or whatever them.

I want to have quite a few views in a certain activity (I've got my reasons, I know it's bad ;) ), and I want them detached from one another. Is there a way to do this? Otherwise, you make some small, irrelevant view GONE, and the applications lags because unnecessary perform traversals are made.

Is there a way to optimize the architecture of the views in order to be sure for that?

Thanks in advance,
Dan